# List<Map<String, List<>>> in BaseAdapter, Android

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, baseadapter

This question has been asked previously. Sorry, I am new to Android, those answers didn't helped me.

I am trying to parse the following json using retrofit,Android. In the json below, objects **4** and **1** are **Dynamic**. So I am using Map to get the data.

```
 {  
"effect_list":[  
  {  
     "4":[  
        {  
           "effects_id":"18",
           "effects_name":"Band 1"
        },
        {  
           "effects_id":"19",
           "effects_name":"Band 2"
        }
     ],
     "1":[  
        {  
           "effects_id":"1",
           "effects_name":"Background Blur"
        },
        {  
           "effects_id":"4",
           "effects_name":"Blemish Removal"
        }
     ]
  }
]
}
```

Now I want to display the json data inside listview using **BaseAdapter**.

I tried

**MyContactAdapter2.java**

```
public class MyContactAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> contactList;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    // Constructors
    public MyContactAdapter2(Context context, List<Map<String, List<EffectList>>> objects) {

        this.context = context;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        contactList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return contactList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public EffectList getItem(int position) {
        return (EffectList) contactList.get(position);  <----- ERROR HERE DURING RUNTIME
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.get_layout_row_view, parent, false);
            vh = MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder.create((RelativeLayout) view);
            view.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        EffectList item = getItem(position);  <----- ERROR HERE DURING RUNTIME


        vh.textViewName.setText(item.getEffectsId());
        vh.textViewEmail.setText(item.getEffectsName());

        return vh.rootView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public final RelativeLayout rootView;
        public final ImageView imageView;
        public final TextView textViewName;
        public final TextView textViewEmail;

        private ViewHolder(RelativeLayout rootView, ImageView imageView, TextView textViewName, TextView textViewEmail) {
            this.rootView = rootView;
            this.imageView = imageView;
            this.textViewName = textViewName;
            this.textViewEmail = textViewEmail;
        }

        public static MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder create(RelativeLayout rootView) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView textViewName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            TextView textViewEmail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
            return new MyContactAdapter2.ViewHolder(rootView, imageView, textViewName, textViewEmail);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error during Runtime.

**java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to my class**

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `Map<String,List<EffectList>>` from `getItem` method because `contactList` contains Map as items:

```
@Override
    public Map<String,List<EffectList>> getItem(int position) {
        return  contactList.get(position);   
    }
```

And in `getView`  use keys to access values from Map:

```
   Map<String,List<EffectList>> map=getItem(position);
   List<EffectList> effectList = map.get("KEY_NAME");
   // get item from effectList using for loop
```

Comment: thanks for the response.now i am getting following error  Incompatible types.
Required:com.example.prakash.pix91.get.Templates.pixjson.EffectList
Found:java.util.Map<java.lang.String,
java.util.List<com.example.prakash.pix91.get.Templates.pixjson.EffectList>>  in **EffectList item = getItem(position);**